# Compilation Error: ChatterAnswersAuthProviderRegistration

Tags: apex, error-messages, compile-error

I'm trying to validate a new apex class, but ran into a slew of test failures. Afterward I went to compile all my classes and got the following error (same error I get with the aforementioned validation):

> ChatterAnswersAuthProviderRegistration: line 17, column 2: Invalid
>   field UserPermissionsChatterAnswersUser for SObject User

I haven't seen this before, and it's an old class that was added before my time, so I'm looking for any guidance as to why it's seemingly just now causing problems. Here's the class it's referring to:

```
global class ChatterAnswersAuthProviderRegistration implements Auth.RegistrationHandler{
global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
  Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
  String accountId = null;
  try { 
    accountId = new ChatterAnswersRegistration().createAccount(data.firstname, data.lastname, Site.getAdminId());
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Database.rollback(sp);
    return null;
  }
  User u = new User();
  u.FirstName = data.firstname;
  u.LastName = data.lastname;
  u.Username = accountId + '@facebook.com';
  u.Email = data.email;
  u.CommunityNickname = data.email.substring(0,  data.email.indexOf('@')) + System.currentTimeMillis();
  u.UserPermissionsChatterAnswersUser = true;
  //If using this registration handler with Salesforce Community registration then specify the profileid to associated with the new user.
  //This profile is used only for Salesforce Community site registration and not for standalone Force.com site registration.
  //u.profileId = '';
  Site.setPortalUserAsAuthProvider(u, accountId);
  return u;
}

global void updateUser(Id userId, Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
  Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
  User u = [SELECT Contact.email, Contact.firstName, Contact.lastName FROM User WHERE id=:userId];
  u.Contact.email = data.email;
  u.Contact.firstName = data.firstName;
  u.Contact.lastName = data.lastName;
  u.firstName = data.firstName;
  u.lastName = data.lastName;
  u.email = data.email;
  try {
    update u;
    update u.Contact;
   } catch (Exception e) {
    Database.rollback(sp);
  }
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is chatter enabled in your org ?

Comment: yes, but I don't know what "Chatter Answers" is

Comment: Its one of the features of platform .Check if API version matches .May be your apex version has changed

Comment: The most recent classes has API v37, but the ChatterAnswersAuthProviderRegistration class had API v31 -- how could that cause a problem?

Comment: The field might have been depreciated in recent releases .ChatterAnswers are retiring as per latest release .So if your users are using the functionality revert the version to 31 .

Comment: Did some digging -- does this appear to be related? https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XHfAAM